# No internet connection after setuping OpenConnect server on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, vpn, routing

```
ip tuntap add mode tun dev vpn0
ip addr add 192.168.2.2/24 dev vpn0

# systemctl restart ocserv
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

```
#ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:00:04:c4:b9:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 66.42.108.48/23 brd 66.42.109.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 85512sec preferred_lft 85512sec
    inet6 2001:19f0:6001:5689:5400:4ff:fec4:b9c3/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2591893sec preferred_lft 604693sec
    inet6 fe80::5400:4ff:fec4:b9c3/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: vpn0: <NO-CARRIER,POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 scope global vpn0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
#
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
#
# sysctl -a | grep forwarding | grep ipv4
net.ipv4.conf.all.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.vpn0.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.vpn0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.vpn0.mc_forwarding = 0
#
```

openconnect config:

```
device = vpns0
tcp-port = 8443
ipv4-network = 192.168.2.0/24
route = default
```

Connection success. Internet do not works.
`ping 8.8.8.8` not work.
ping of vpn server works.

Connection from Windows home to Linux VPS

Comment: Please provide your routes ip route show. You probably need to use split tunneling to not route internet traffic over the vpn, but route it through your default interface

Answer (score 0):

You need add a static route which routes internet traffic over your default interface. Something like this

```
ip route add default via <your_gateway_ip> dev enp1s0
```